# Mongoose - search in nested arrays

Tags: mongoose

I have following document model

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8da9d567698b640243aed7"),
    "reserved_days" : [ 
        {
            "room" : {
                "room_id" : "8",
                "name" : "Бюджет"
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a8da9d567698b640243aed6")
        }, 
        {
            "room" : {
                "room_id" : "8",
                "name" : "Бюджет"
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a8da9d567698b640243aed5")
        }, 
    ],
}
```

I need to find days with room_id 8

I try the following

```
Reservation.find({'reserved_days': { $elemMatch: { 'room': {$elemMatch: { 'room_id': 8 }}}}}, function (err, result) {
        res.send(result)
    })
```

but it doest work, returns empty array

How to perform query correctly ?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. You have multiple room with matching criteria. You  are sending number 8 comparing with string 8 in database so no matches are returned. You can just use dot notation for single criteria. Something like .`find('reserved_days.room.room_id':'8')`

Comment: I tried, this doesn't work

Comment: What specifically is not working ? does it not return any values or is it not in expected format ?

Comment: yes, it returns no values, empty array.

Comment: Do you mind showing me the query ? Does your query return any data without the filter ?

Comment: yes, without room filter it works. query is following object { room: { 'reserved_days.room.room_id': 4 } }

Comment: So is your room string value or numeric value ? It should be `{ 'reserved_days.room.room_id': "4" }`

Comment: both don't work

Comment: It looks like you may have problem somewhere in other part of code.

Comment: I dont think so, other queries work fine

Comment: Can you show me the complete query ? Did you try hardcoding the room id for testing purposes ? Add `mongoose.set('debug', true);` at the top to see what queries get sent to to server.